# Wierd routing issues with towerjs

Tags: towerjs

if my router says

```
@resources "homes"
```

and i navigate to
`/homes`

everything loads

but if i have

```
@match '/', to: 'homes#index'
```

and navigate to `/`

nothing happens. I just get my template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this myself and sent a PR and it seems to work as expected.